# Why is my javascript replacing everything in the html document?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm learning to code on my own and have startet with javascript but i have a problem with my code and cant find the issue please explain me why my code replace all elements in the html document with the javascript result

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
<html>
<head>
<title>JS</title>
</head>
<body> 
<h1> Whats your name? </h1>
FirstName: <input type="text" id="first" value="">
LastName: <input type="text" id="second" value="">
<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
<script id="jsbin-javascript">

function myFunction() {
var first = document.getElementById("first").value;
var second = document.getElementById("second").value;
var fullName = first + " " + second;
var x = fullName;
console.log(x);
document.write(x);
}

</script>
</body>  
</html>
```

[JSBIN LINK](http://jsbin.com/yetebasaxa/2/edit?html,js,output)

Comment: Calling `document.write()` after the document has loaded already will erase the entire document. Don't use `document.write()` here.

Comment: Because you use document.write()